# system verilog assertions: Using a reg value in a repition operator

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I am trying to do something like this:

```
assert property (@(posedge clk) disable iff (!rst) a[*c] -> $rose(b))
```

Here `c` is not a 'constant' but a value coming from some bits of a register. eg: `reg[4:0]` which is written only once. The check is to see if `b` is asserted only when a is high for "c" number of cycles.

However, SVAs do not accept a variable like this : `[*reg[4:0]]`. Any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

Introduce a local variable `ctr`. At every posedge a new assertion with a new instance of `ctr` will be created. Set `ctr` equal to the value in `reg1`. Check that `a` is true throughout the down count. Decrement the counter as long as it is larger than zero. The `(ctr>0, ctr--)[*0:$]` statement will count down until `ctr == 0` is true.

You might want to change `(ctr>0, ctr--)[*0:$]` to `(ctr>0, ctr--)[*1:$]`, depending on what results you expect if `reg == 0`.

```
property pr_aRegTimes;
  integer ctr;
  disable iff (!rst)
  @(posedge clk)
    (1, ctr = reg1) ##0 a throughout ((ctr>0, ctr--)[*0:$] ##1 (ctr == 0)) |-> $rose(b);
endproperty

as_aRegTimes: assert property (pr_aRegTimes)
  else $error("aRegTimes failed");
```

Working example:
http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Xh9

Sources:

https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/assertions/
http://www.win.tue.nl/~jschmalt/teaching/2IMF20/SvaFvTutorialHVC2013.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
property pr_aRegTimes;
  integer ctr;
  disable iff (!rst)
  @(posedge clk)
    ($rose(a), ctr = reg1) ##0 (a&&ctr>0,ctr--)[*] |-> $rose(b);
endproperty
```